# Upgrade CakePHP install from 3.0.13 to 3.8

Tags: cakephp, composer-php, migration, cakephp-3.x

I have a working installation with CakePHP 3.0.13. I'd like to upgrade to 3.8 before trying to jump to the 4.x branch. I've launched this: `composer require cakephp/cakephp:3.8.12` and I get the next results:

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - cakephp/migrations 1.3.2 requires cakephp/cakephp 3.0.* -> no matching package found.
    - cakephp/migrations 1.3.2 requires cakephp/cakephp 3.0.* -> no matching package found.
    - cakephp/migrations 1.3.2 requires cakephp/cakephp 3.0.* -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for cakephp/migrations 1.3.2 -> satisfiable by cakephp/migrations[1.3.2].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

It seems there is a dependency problem with the migrations package: Cake requires an upgrade on Migrations, but Migrations requires that cake remains in 3.0.*. In `vendor/cakephp/migrations/composer.json` I have:

```
    ...
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4",
        "robmorgan/phinx": ">=0.4.2 <0.5.0",
        "cakephp/cakephp": "3.0.*"
    },
    ...
```

I've tried also to upgrade Migrations using composer, but I get the opposite problem: cakephp should be upgraded, so I'm stuck. Any suggestions? Thx in advance!

Comment: Upgrade all dependencies at once, not one by one. Delete the `vendor` folder and the `composer.lock` file if there are still issues, even when all dependencies should be compatible.

Comment: I've removed `vendor/*` and `composer.lock`. Then I've edited `composer.json` with `"cakephp/cakephp": "3.8.12",` and launched `composer install`. I have the same result (apart from others about PHP version): `-Installation request for cakephp/migrations 1.3.2 -> satisfiable by cakephp/migrations[1.3.2]. -  - cakephp/migrations 1.3.2 requires cakephp/cakephp 3.0.* -> no matching package found.`

Comment: As mentioned, upgrade _all_ dependencies at once, require the compatible versions for CakePHP, for Migrations, and for whatever else dependencies you have in your application's `composer.json`.

Comment: Can you share **your own** `composer.json`? Whatever another package requires might not be that relevant

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the problem. As @ndm and @Nico-haase pointed I've reviewed my `composer.json` file. Between other packages I had:

`...
"cakephp/cakephp": "~3.0.13",
"cakephp/migrations": "1.3.2",
...`
 
...when I tried to upgrade CakePHP to 3.8.12, I should also have upgraded Migrations, 'cause migrations 1.3.2 runs in cake 3.0.13, not 3.8. That's why it didn't work. Now I've used 3.8.12 for Cake and simply `@stable` for migrations.

`...
"cakephp/cakephp": "~3.8.12",
"cakephp/migrations": "@stable",
...`

After upgrading also the platform requirements (php versions, libs, ...), I've launched `composer install` successfully. Thx a lot!!